# Unable to access rest api using Postman for Spring Boot Application with Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to create a Spring Boot API, but I am not getting anything in my logs and U am unable to access using Postman and cURL. Even "hello world" example is also not running.

Changing port did not work as different ports need to be allocated for different services and in my scenario port 8080 is for tomcat and 8081 for mongo-express.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from com.example.quiz.repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>quiz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>quiz</name>
    <description>quiz project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

QuizApplication.java

```java
package com.example.quiz;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController

public class QuizApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuizApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Question.java

```java
package com.example.quiz.model;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@Document(collection = "question")
public class Question {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String questionText;

    public Question(
            String questionText
    ) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
    }
}
```

QuestionRepository.java

```java
package com.example.quiz.repository;

import com.example.quiz.model.Question;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends MongoRepository<Question, String> {
    List<Question> findAll();
}
```

QuizController.java

```java
package com.example.quiz.controller;

import com.example.quiz.model.Question;
import com.example.quiz.repository.QuestionRepository;
import com.example.quiz.service.QuestionService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")
@RestController
public class QuestionController {

    @Autowired
    QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Autowired
    QuestionService questionService;

    @GetMapping("/question")
    public Question setQuestion(Question question) {
        return questionRepository.insert(new Question(
            question.getQuestionText()
        ));
    }
    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<Question> getQuestion() {
        return questionService.getAllQuestions();
    }
      
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

QuizService.java

```java
package com.example.quiz.service;

import com.example.quiz.model.Question;
import com.example.quiz.repository.QuestionRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class QuestionService {

    @Autowired
    QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        return questionRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=rootuser
spring.data.mongodb.password=rootpass
spring.data.mongodb.database=quizdatabase
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
server.error.include-message = always
```

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - data:/data
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=rootuser
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=rootuser
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=rootpass
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  data: {}

networks:
  default:
    name: mongodb_network
```

Logs

```
2021-08-15 18:42:56.878  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.quiz.QuizApplication         : Starting QuizApplication using Java 1.8.0_151 on Vishwajeets-MacBook-Pro-2.local with PID 99293 (/Users/vishwajeetkumar/Downloads/quiz3Test/target/classes started by vishwajeetkumar in /Users/vishwajeetkumar/Downloads/quiz3Test)
2021-08-15 18:42:56.898  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.quiz.QuizApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-08-15 18:42:57.641  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-08-15 18:42:57.643  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-08-15 18:43:00.470  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-08-15 18:43:00.546  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 68 ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interfaces.
2021-08-15 18:43:06.280  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-08-15 18:43:06.411  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-08-15 18:43:06.429  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]
2021-08-15 18:43:07.227  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-08-15 18:43:07.228  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 9569 ms
2021-08-15 18:43:09.206  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
2021-08-15 18:43:09.464  INFO 99293 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:70}] to localhost:27017
2021-08-15 18:43:09.464  INFO 99293 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:71}] to localhost:27017
2021-08-15 18:43:09.468  INFO 99293 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=13, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=93274206}
2021-08-15 18:43:10.444  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-08-15 18:43:15.615  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-08-15 18:43:15.715  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.quiz.QuizApplication         : Started QuizApplication in 24.388 seconds (JVM running for 28.746)
```

Comment: Didn't test it, but from general reading, default port is 8080, if you exposed 8081 that will not help, change docker port or change port of spring to 8081

Comment: docker port is by default running on 8081 and when tried to run after changing spring to 8081 it gave error as port is already in use.

Comment: you miss understood me,
    2021-08-15 18:43:06.280  INFO 99293 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
this is the spring port, you didn't expose 8080, you need to expose 8080 or change the tomcat port

Comment: I got it tomcat 8080 port should be used to send the api request not the docker port 8081